# How do I use insignia.exe to codesign a wix bundle

Tags: wix, wix3.6, authenticode

I created a wix bundle which was working properly before codesigning. After googling and checking wix documentation, I got to know that I need to use insignia.exe for code signing the wix bundle.  Please any idea on how to use this tool. Thanks in Anticipation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I use the next command sequence (it's a part of my cmd file. Certificate is stored in a file on hard drive. If you want to sign your installer by the certificate from the store just fix signing part. All result code check is omitted)

```
set INSIGNIA_PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.8\bin\insignia.exe"

rem Detach engine

del /q engine.exe

%INSIGNIA_PATH% -ib Setup.exe -o engine.exe

rem Sign engine

SignTool.exe sign /f certificate.pfx /p CERT_PASSWORD /t TIMESTAMP_URL engine.exe

rem Attach engine

%INSIGNIA_PATH% -ab engine.exe Setup.exe -o ProductSetup.exe

rem Sign bundle

SignTool.exe sign /f certificate.pfx /p CERT_PASSWORD /t TIMESTAMP_URL ProductSetup.exe
```

Comment: one thing to watch out for: make sure there is no space between the variable name INSIGNIA_PATH, the = sign, and the path. Otherwise the variable won't get the value assigned to it.